# Not making Django project in PyCharm

Tags: django, pycharm, new-project

I have a problem when i try to create a new Django project in PyCharm.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS14L.png)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask a good question.
Also, your problem seems more related to your system and developement IDE, rather than a programming related question (which this site is for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that python is still not the part of your environment PATH variable in your PC.

Go to -->

1). `start` ( if you're using Windows ) and search `Edit the system environment variables` and click on it.

2). Now click on `Environment Variables` and check in `system variables` that the `python` is in your `PATH` OR  Not.